# Chrome is blocking json downloads - is there a way to prevent this?

Tags: json, google-chrome, download

Today, Chrome started blocking downloads of json files for us. We use them in our internal content management system for moving files from one environment to another. But it isn't just us. We also use Firebase and can't do an export from there either. I know about the workaround to click Show all and keep the "dangerous file", but how can we prevent Chrome from blocking them in the first place?

Comment: There really should be a site setting for this, but at least for now it looks like the only way is to disable the whole Safe Browsing feature.

Comment: why on earth would a file containing no executable code be dangerous in the first place? this is definitely a fail on chrome, one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with Chrome blocking various extensions downloads, hopefully this gets resolved soon.

Comment: this isn't an answer